# PHPUnit - Setter doesn't modify my mock

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I use PHPUnit for my unit tests (Symfony2 app).

This is my method that I want test (simplified):

```
public function __construct(Email $email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}
public function sendEmail()
{
    // Here, more logic and condition, it's simplified
    if ($this->email->getOk() === 1) {
        $this->email->setSendEmail(1);
    }

    return $this->email;
}
```

And my test:

```
$emailMock = $this->getMock(Email::class);
$emailMock->method('getOk')->will($this->returnValue(1));
$emailMock->method('setSendEmail')->will($this->returnArgument(0));

$email = new Email($emailMock);
$emailModified = $email->sendEmail();
var_dump($emailModified->getSendEmail()); // Returns NULL
```

My class Email is a Doctrine Entity (the setter and getter is inside) [(an example of entity)](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php)

How can I test if my mock is hydrated by my class?
I want to know if my method works by looking if my object is hydrated.

---

**Edit**

I try an other method :

```
   $object = $this->getMock(MyClass::class);
   $object->method('setPosition')->will(
            $this->returnCallback(
                $pos = function ($arg) {
                    return $arg;
                }
            )
        );

   $object->method('getPosition')->will($this->returnValue($pos));


    $method = new \ReflectionMethod(MyClass::class, 'testMethod');
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    $res = $method->invoke(new MyClass($object));

   var_dump($res->getPosition()) // Return inexploitable Closure
```

I would like that `$object->getPosition()` return `1` when I execute `$object->setPosition(1)` from my external class MyClass() that I test.

Comment: Your mock specifies that `getOk` will be called, but in your code it is `getWait` that is called.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Did you forget to call [`setMethods()`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.examples.SubjectTest.php)? It's used to declare the overridden methods.

Comment: I edited my post, I hope this is understandable

Comment: @A.L Don't think `setMethods()` is required when not using `getMockBuilder()`?

Comment: @johnnyevolunium There are no brackets after your call to `getOk`.

Comment: @Drumbeg I have added an edit, it's maybe more understandable and it is maybe a best approach

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I ended up mocking `getter` and `setter` to be functional like such

```
    // Mock setter
    $exceptionEvent->expects($this->once())->method('setResponse')->willReturnCallback(
        function($arg) use ($exceptionEvent) {
            $exceptionEvent->response = $arg;
        }
    );
    // Mock getter
    $exceptionEvent->expects($this->once())->method('getResponse')->willReturnCallback(
        function() use ($exceptionEvent) {
            return $exceptionEvent->response;
        }
    );
```

The class I am testing takes `$exceptionEvent` and calls `setResponse()` on it. This solution works for me, I then make assertions against `$exceptionEvent->getResponse()` after I run it through said class.

Answer (score 0):

Even later, and just a modification of what Matt did above:

```
$storage = null;
$mock    = $this->createMock(MyClass::class);

$mock->expects($this->any())->method('set')->willReturnCallback(
    function ($arg) use ($mock, &$storage) {
        $storage = $arg;

        return $mock;
    }
);

$mock->expects($this->any())->method('get')->willReturnCallback(
    function () use (&$storage) {
        return $storage;
    }
);
```

This allows to store the values "locally" within the test, and doesn't expect you to have visibility to the object properties.

`$storage` is sent in as a reference to edit the contents of the variable in the tests scope, not just callback's scope.